# How to select inline-block elements displayed to the right and left of a given element in a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list (`<ul>`) with many `<li>` elements. The `<ul>` element has a width of 100%, which fits 1 to "n" number of `<li>` inline-block elements next to one another, depending on the browser window size. Therefore, the list contains x number of lines each with "n" number of elements.

Given one element, using jQuery I would like to select all other elements in the same line. How can I do that?

In this image, I show 2 cases with different browser window sizes. The elements I want to select are highlighted in green.
[image]

Comment: The issue I see directly with this is the fact that you want to select elements based on rows that can be different depending on window size.. It would be much easier if you could work with `classes` for the elements and do something like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/m4vLvobn/1/)..

Comment: Check my answer it will work for your scenario. If the width of browser will change dynamically then add this into a $(window).resize() fn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to identify a given `<li>'s` siblings on same row by matching the position as they would be same.

Here is the sample code you can use

```
var givenLi=$($('.ulnav li').get(6));
var sameRowLis=[];
givenLi.siblings().each(function(){
    if(givenLi.position().top === $(this).position().top){
        sameRowLis.push($(this)[0]);
    }
});
console.log($(sameRowLis));
```

The sameRowLis would give you what you expect, however this wont include the initial given `<li>`

If you want it to include the given `<li>` then change the each selector as below `'givenLi.parent().children().each...'`

Comment: It works! Somehow, I thought the jquery `.position().top` would only work for elements with absolute or relative positions defining a `top` css value. However, as shown in your answer, `.position().top` works for inline-blocks, and other elements. I adapted your answer to my use case, using: `var sameRowLis=$();` rather than `var sameRowLis=[];`, and `sameRowLis.add($(this));` rather than `sameRowLis.push($(this)[0]);`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Didnt knew I could add into jQuery object, so did the workaround.

Comment: If you use `.add`, just make sure you use it like this: `sameRowLis = sameRowLis.add($(this));`, otherwise sameRowLis will not be updated in the each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a bit unclear, if all the `<li>`s are inside the same `<ul>`, then you can't in any simple way select whatever `<li>` that is *visually* before or after *n*. If you select the last element on a "row" then it would also select the first `li` on the next row, as that next `li` is after the selected one in the dom

On the other hand, If you have several `<ul>` tags with `<li>` elements to achieve "rows" of `<li>` both *visually* and in your *code* then you could for example do this.

```
$('.container ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
    var prevLi = $(this).prev(), nextLi = $(this).next();
    //your code here
})
```

Comment: I added an image to make it clearer. I cannot do what you suggest as I do not know before hand which elements will visually fall in the same line, as the number of elements depends on window size...